# C language copying contents of a pointer byte by byte infinite loop

Tags: c, pointers, memory

I'm trying to copy the contents of a pointer byte by byte to another pointer, but I am getting stuck in the for loop in the function below. I believe it could be something C language related. Any clue why this might be happening?

```
void copy_COW(unsigned int pid, unsigned int vaddr) {
    //pid is the current process id,  vaddr is the double mapped page which has a fault
    dprintf("copying on write...\n"); dprintf("\n");

    //set fresh_page_index to perm writeable
    unsigned int writeable_perm =  PTE_P | PTE_W | PTE_U;   
    unsigned int* contents_to_copy;
    unsigned int* fresh_page_index;
    unsigned int i;

    //allocate fresh page
    fresh_page_index = (unsigned int*) alloc_page(pid, vaddr, writeable_perm);
    contents_to_copy = (unsigned int*) get_ptbl_entry_by_va(pid, vaddr);

    //fresh_page_index |= writeable_perm; //make page writeable, usable by user and present

    //copy contents at vaddr (dir, page) to fresh_page_index by looping thru
    for (i=0; i<4096 ;i++) 
    {
        //dprintf("i is %d \n", i); 
        char byteToCopy = contents_to_copy[i];

        fresh_page_index[i] = byteToCopy;
    }

    //update memory mapping in pdir to use fresh_page_index
    set_ptbl_entry_by_va(pid, vaddr, (unsigned int) fresh_page_index, writeable_perm);

}
```

Comment: Even without taking the infinite loop into account, the mere act to copying by `unsigned int` -> `char` -> `unsigned int` is not going to be correct in any way.

Comment: program getting stuck is usually a sign of access violation. You should run the code with a debugger, you probably would get a segfault.

Comment: Why not use memcpy like memcpy( fresh_page_index, contents_to_copy, 4096 )?

Comment: Both your source and target pointers are of type `unsigned int*` but you are evidently trying to copy bytes (`char byteToCopy = ...`).

Comment: If one page has 4096 bytes you are writing out of bounds since you try to write 4096 `int`s, which take most likely more space.

Comment: Why don't you declare `fresh_page_index` and `contents_to_copy` as `char *`?

Comment: `(unsigned int) fresh_page_index` here you are casting `unsigned int *` to `unsigned int` which is not a good idea.

Comment: Why not copy 1024 `unsigned int` instead of 4096 `char`?

Answer (score 0):

In your copy loop, you are reading 4096 characters, and writing 4096 integers. In the loop, a character read will be sign-extended to an integer and written to the integer array `fresh_page_index`.

You either need to adapt your type definition or, much simpler, use `memcpy`.